# How we can give same name to the multiple textbox which are created by a loop

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts

I have created multiple textboxes/textfields using a `for` loop in JSP (or Struts2). The textboxes/textfields are created at runtime based on the condition, therefore i am unable to say exact number of textboxes. I have code which is executed using the `onFocus` of each of these textboxes and perform the same function for each one, for example when i `onfocus` on textbox, the calender will be opened. The function which is executed is performed based on the "name" of the textbox. But whenever i run this JSP and onfocus on the textbox, it executes only for the first textbox rather than all of them. please help me with this, or give me some suggestions  what i need to  do in this scenario. Thank You

Comment: please provide relevant html and javascript

Comment: JSP is a technology for generating web pages therefore you seem to be talking about web forms. But in this context, the jsp/java ccode (serverside) has no visibility of the 'onfocus' event (clientside). This seems to be a question about javascript - but you don't mention that. You've not provided any code.

Comment: It's difficult to answer you without seeing the JSP. My guess is that after the JSP compilation, your textboxes get the same name attribute, so the javascript function works fine only for the first element having this name. Difficult to state without code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try array variable in textbox

```
<s:iterator...>
    <S:textfield name="elementname[]" id="elementname[]" onfocus="javascript:funcName(this)"/>
</s:iterator>
```

in script

```
var variablename = document.getElementsByName('elementname[]');
for(var i=0;i<transferBusinessId.length;i++)
{
     alert(variablename [i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when calling the javascript function on focus , pass this as one of the parameter which will give the selected element. You can do something like this

```
<s:textfield name="yourElemetnName" onfocus="javascript:funcName(this)">
```

in javascript function

```
function funcName(element){
 alert("selected the correct element -- "  + element.id);
 //the real work goes here

}
```

Hope this helps :)